# Display file extensions on windows 7 and later

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

How can I display file extensions in folders on Windows 7 (or later)?

I can't find it since I upgraded from WinXP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *Folder Options* control panel contains an option to show/hide file extensions for known file types. By default, it's set to *Hide*.

To get to the control panel is simple (but slightly different in each version of Windows):

- In Windows 7, press <kbd>Win</kbd> and type *Folder Options*, and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- In Windows 8, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and type *Folder Options*, then select it from the search results.
- In Windows 10, press <kbd>Win</kbd> and type *File Explorer Options*, and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Under the *View* tab, there's an *Advanced settings* tree. You should see *Hide extensions for known file types.* checked in the list. Uncheck it, and click *OK*.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 8 you can see the file name extensions by:

1. Open File Explorer.
2. Select View option from the Ribbon
3. Check **File name extensions** check box

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Windows 8 personally, but I guess it's still the same as on Windows 7.

- Launch Control Panel
- Search for Folder Options and open it
- Uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types".

Comment: This isn't a very good answer.  You don't even use Windows 8.  So why are you answering a question with "I guess its the same" when you don't actually know?  Its actually isn't the same as both `sidran32` and `Rakib Ansary` have proven by their answer.

Comment: Gee as it turns out it is the same for W8 as it was for W7, smarty pants. Folder Options in Control panel is exactly the same for W8.