# show file extensions in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, file-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display the extension of the file on windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/494312/how-to-display-the-extension-of-the-file-on-windows-8)

I am not able to show file extensions in windows 8.I can not find the folder options,that used to be there in windows 7 on the top right cornet to show file extensions and hidden folders.

where are they in windows 8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Open up File Explorer (formerly known as Windows Explorer)
2. Expand the ribbon bar by clicking the down arrow on the far right of the menu
3. Click on the View tab of the ribbon bar
4. Select the "File name extensions" checkbox

Answer (score 2):

1. Open up Windows Explorer
2. Click on View
3. Click on "File name extensions"

Comment: Not much profit :)