# How do I completely turn off Windows Defender in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

As discussed [here](http://turn_off_windows_defender_in_windows_10_completely), Windows Defender seems to be the cause that make File Explorer become very slow to use.

So I want to turn it off completely - using `Real-time Protection off` is just a temporary turn-off; Windows 10 will turn it back on later.

[image]

Comment: http://wmug.co.uk/wmug/b/pwin/archive/2015/05/12/quickly-disable-windows-defender-on-windows-10-using-powershell

Comment: Related: *[How to turn off Windows Defender permanently](https://superuser.com/questions/950744)*

Comment: Your link has always been broken; probably the title was used instead of the URL (I had to modify it). Can you provide the URL (by editing your question, not here in comments)? And flag this comment when done.

Comment: These answers no longer work in Windows 10, [but there is a solution here](https://superuser.com/a/1590129/40928)

Comment: [Permanent way to disable Windows defender](https://superuser.com/a/1590129/40928) in later builds of Windows 10

Answer (score 5):

[Take ownership](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.210) of the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender`. Now set the value `DisableAntiSpyware` to `1`.

This stops Windows Defender.

p.s.
[Download link](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.57) for the tool.

[image]

In newer Windows 10 Builds (1703, 1709), this is not working any longer. Windows prevents creating keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender`.

Here, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender`, create a DWORD `DisableAntiSpyware` and set it to `1`:

[image]

Now reboot and Defender should not start again.

**Attention:
[DisableAntiSpyware is ignored for Windows 10 (1903 and newer versions)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/security-malware-windows-defender-disableantispyware) since August 2020:**

> DisableAntiSpyware is intended to be used by OEMs and IT Pros to
> disable Microsoft Defender Antivirus and deploy another antivirus
> product during deployment. This is a legacy setting that is no longer
> necessary as Microsoft Defender antivirus automatically turns itself
> off when it detects another antivirus program. This setting is not
> intended for consumer devices, and we’ve decided to remove this
> registry key. This change is included with Microsoft Defender
> Antimalware platform versions 4.18.2007.8 and higher KB 4052623.
> Enterprise E3 and E5 editions will be released at a future date. Note
> that this setting is protected by tamper protection. Tamper protection
> is available in all Home and Pro editions of Windows 10 version 1903
> and higher and is enabled by default. The impact of the
> DisableAntiSpyware removal is limited to Windows 10 versions prior to
> 1903 using Microsoft Defender Antivirus.

Comment: For me this was the only thing that worked on one machine. The group policy setting had no effect, even though on another computer that worked. Also if the key doesn't exist, just create a DWORD one.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I also see `DisableAntiVirus` in the list. Do we need to make it 1 as `DisableAntiSpyware`?

Comment: Yeah, set both entries and see if the defender is completely disabled.

Comment: It's still turned back on @magicandre1981

Comment: hm, this is strange. I set the values in Win8 and it never turns on again.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you have researched already, but here are a few quick potential solutions for you.

***TEMPORARY OFF:***

1. Open Windows Defender by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button. In the search box, type Defender, and then, in the list of results, click Windows Defender.
2. Click Tools, and then click Options.
3. Click Administrator, select or clear the Use this program check box, and then click Save. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

LINK: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/turn-windows-defender-on-off#turn-windows-defender-on-off=windows-7

***PERMANENT OFF:***

A big thanks to TOPGUNDCP for the possible solution here.

PS. I have not tested it (as I do not wish to disable my own Windows Defender), but this seems like a good starting point.

1. Open Admin Command Prompt and type: ***gpedit.msc***
2. Manoeuver to: Computer Configuration->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->Windows Defender
3. Double click on "Turn Off Windows Defender" and select "Enabled" then click "Apply"

**WARNING:** After turn off "Windows Defender", you might not be able to turn it back on. I suggest before trying this, make a backup image so you can restore to the way it was.

LINK: http://www.tenforums.com/antivirus-firewalls-system-security/5879-permanently-disable-windows-defender-post234396.html?s=90095f90f13d22416a5d1751ede0bd64#post234396

Answer (score 1):

One can disable the Real-time protection of Windows Defender via the Settings app,
but this will be only temporary, as Windows will re-enable it automatically after
the next reboot.

To permanently turn off Real-time protection, I list below two methods.
Reboot is required after each one.

**Method 1 : Using the Local Group Policy Editor**

This method requires Windows 10 version Pro or higher.

- Open the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Navigate to:
  *Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Windows Defender Antivirus/Real-time Protection*
- Double-click *Turn off real-time protection*
- Select *Enabled*
- Click *OK*.

**Method 2 : Registry editing**

This method will work for all Windows versions.

Create and execute the following `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection]
"DisableRealtimeMonitoring"=dword:00000001
```

---

Changing these settings requires that Tamper protection be off.

For more information about this feature see the Microsoft article
[Protect security settings with tamper protection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-antivirus/prevent-changes-to-security-settings-with-tamper-protection).

For methods of disabling this feature see the article
[How to Turn On or Off Tamper Protection for Windows Defender Antivirus in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/123792-turn-off-tamper-protection-windows-defender-antivirus.html).

However, turning Tamper protection off but not through the Settings app
requires taking ownership of the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Features`,
which might cause problems in the future with Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

After trying various things, I ended up finding the script linked below, and it worked perfectly.  I'm hoping this helps others still struggling to free their CPU from this "protection" software.

**https://github.com/TairikuOokami/Windows/blob/main/Microsoft%20Defender%20Disable.bat**

### Detailed Instructions

#### 1. Create a text file and name it DisableDefender.bat

1. Right-click on desktop
2. Select New -> Text Document
3. Change the name of the new file from `New Text Document.txt` to `DisableDefender.bat` and click "Yes" to confirm the extension change.

**NOTE**: If you did it right, you will be prompted to confirm that you want to change the file name extensions.  If you were not asked to confirm at step **1.3**, then you likely do not have File Extensions visible.  Turn them on by following instructions **[here](https://superuser.com/questions/494312/display-file-extensions-on-windows-7-and-later)** and start over at step **1.1**.

#### 2. Paste the script into the BAT file

1. Go to the link above.
2. Copy all the text in the file
3. Right-click on DisableDefender.bat file and select Edit
4. Paste the script into the file, save, and close

#### 3. Run several times as Administrator and Restart

1. Right click on DisableDefender.bat file and select Run as administrator.
2. Repeat this a couple more times.
3. Restart the computer.

If it worked, then...

- `MsMpEng.exe` will no longer be running.
- The various `Windows Defender...` services will be disabled.
- Your CPU will have far less usage.

Special thanks to [Tairiku Ookami](https://github.com/TairikuOokami) for creating and posting the script.