# Explorer completely freezes when creating or deleting a file/folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, freeze

I've had this issue for months now and I really don't know what to do except reinstall Windows 10. I run 2 SSDs in RAID 0 and CrystalDiskInfo reports they're 100% OK. However, when I either create a file or delete a file, the whole explorer basically freezes for up to 60 seconds. Here are some cases where it happens and doesn't happen:

- Downloading a file (opening it works fine, but "Show in folder"/open in Explorer freezes it)
- Moving files around freezes it
- Deleting a file, folder, or shortcut freezes it

I've ran pretty much every good software out there to try and fix this, but none of them has worked. I've ran:

- chkdsk
- CCleaner (and Registry Cleaner)
- MalwareBytes

It might be an indexing issue, perhaps? Like it's trying to update the indices, but the index file/database is too large or something.

I would hate to reinstall Windows, so I'm ready to try anything out. Any clues?

Comment: [disable Windows Defender](https://superuser.com/a/988550/174557)

Comment: @magicandre1981 It is already. Disabled it when I installed Windows a long time ago (and it still is disabled).

Comment: try 3rd party file management tool like [Altap Salaander](https://www.altap.cz/salamander/downloads/) and look if it also causes freezes.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Eh no thanks, I'm not trying that. It won't replace Explorer.exe but that's not the issue.

Comment: again, try it or other tools like TotalCommander. here you see if this is an Explorer or Win10 issue

Comment: @magicandre1981 It is 100% a Windows issue. Even after installing TotalCommander, I can't open any folders for ~20-30 seconds.

Comment: If you also have an external HDD, it may be a spin-up issue. Try KeepAliveHD or similar application for each drive letter. Also, what AV are you running? Temporarily disable it to test if it's causing the issue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It doesn't matter if I unplug my WD Black HDD either. It doesn't matter if I write to the HDD or SSD, it still freezes. It doesn't matter if I write now and write in 2 minutes, it will still freeze. I'm not using any AV and Windows Defender is completely disabled.

Comment: I would download Procdump (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump), When it next hangs run in an admin command prompt `procdump -ma -mk explore`.  This should create 2 dump files, the user mode and the kernel mode memory space. Maybe provide links to those?