# Microsoft Defender Antivirus is disabled, but back to normal after reboot. How to disable it permanently?

Tags: windows, anti-virus, reboot, group-policy, windows-defender

I have Windows 10 ver 2004. Since Windows Defender changed to Microsoft Defender Antivirus I'm unable to turn it off. In Local Group Policy (gpedit.msc) under `Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Microsoft Defender Antivirus` there is a key "Turn off Microsoft Defender Antivirus". Every time I check "enable" and log out or reboot the key is back to "Not configured". How to keep it disabled permanently, and therefore turn off Microsoft Defender Antivirus essentially?

[image]
<sub>(source: [windowscentral.com](https://www.windowscentral.com/sites/wpcentral.com/files/styles/xlarge/public/field/image/2020/08/disable-permanently-microsoft-defener-group-policy.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have successfully removed the windows defender service with no side effects so far, other than windows notifying you that the defender service could not start.

Windows 10 Version 2004 build 19041.450

This eliminated defender from the PC

Use a bootable offline registry editor of choice, I used a [windows 7 64bit ERD](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password/247953#247953) disc to do it, not publicly available but can be found. It has a registry editor.

Once booted into the registry editor navigate to

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WinDefend

delete the WinDefend key

I would export the key first, then if you want Defender back you can Merge the saved key back into the registry and reboot.

The key may be returned after certain Windows updates, so you will have to delete it again, thanks IGRACH

Comment: YES. This is the way xD

Comment: Nice find on that!!!

Comment: I still get notifications that my antivirus is off, but so far so good, windows stopped deleting files and making decisions for me.

Comment: That was noted in my answer.

Comment: Why can't normal regedit work?

Comment: Microsoft disabled that registry setting

Comment: I'm able to delete it with just a regular regedit

Comment: No, the key is protected while booted into windows, you must use a boot disk with a regedit tool as described.

Comment: but I can delete it and it doesn't reappear after reboot. I suppose the key is successfully deleted?

Comment: you should get a notification Defender could not start.

Comment: You get notification that defender is stopped after reboot and when you go to setting>antivirus; it says that "Threat service has stopped. Restart it now".

Comment: And yes whole reg key is back after Windows update. You just need to delete it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out a very good workaround for the POLICY Setting getting reset to "Not Configured" every time you restart Group Policy Editor. I had the same problem and guessed out (correctly) that it was **MsMpEng.exe** running in the background that was resetting the policy back to "Not Configured".

So, before making any changes to the policy, head over to *Task Manager*, then to *Performance Monitor* from the Performance tab. Find **MsMpEng.exe** in any of the tabs in it (mostly on top in Memory or CPU tabs) and click on Suspend Process.

Then make the changes as required in the Group Policy Editor. It won't get reverted back. Please reply if it works, or didn't work.

**NOTE** :- Keep the MsMpEng.exe process suspended for as long as you like XD

Answer (score 0):

Use **IceSpringDesktopHelper** to block it without reboot.

Github: https://github.com/baijifeilong/IceSpringDesktopHelper

Snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to delete registry entry without booting from ERD or LiveCD. Just follow the instructions from [this guide](https://www.alitajran.com/turn-off-windows-defender-in-windows-10-permanently/), disable service from autoruns and then delete registry entry from regedit.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please have a look at [how to write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). An answer that's nothing but a link gets usually flagged for low quality, and eventually gets deleted. To prevent that you should [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1679795/edit) your answer and expand it so that the steps to resolving the issue are included; and leave the link as reference. Also please take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to learn how Q&A sites differ from internet forums. [From Review](https://superuser.com/review/first-answers/1083161).