# Disabling Real Time Protection in Windows 10 by a PowerShell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, windows-defender

I'm trying to disable Real Time Protection in Windows 10 by a PowerShell. So far I tried `Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true` and `sc stop WinDefend`, none of them 2 is working. Is there any other command? But only for PowerShell or CMD.

Comment: You cannot, but you can disable defender>>>>https://superuser.com/a/1590129/40928

Comment: No, I need it for powershell or cmd. I'm making a script that turns off defender when started.

Comment: I have never found a way, Microsoft has made is extremely difficult to stop the defender service.

Comment: That sucks. Well I guess I need to buy SSL, that is the only way to do it.

Comment: @mestro65 - There are free SSL certificates that are trusted by every major browser on every major operating system.

Comment: Please tell me which.

Answer (score -1):

same problem here - on some machines, the powershell command is working, on some machines not.
we need to turn of the realtimemonitoring for creating docker containers.
the user is able to turn it off manually, but hey, that's not a good way ;)

Comment: ahhh looks like it's the Tamper-Protection, which when it's on, ignores the powershell commands :) - looking for a way to disable it via code. if i find something, i'll tell you