# Disable Windows Defender in Windows 11

Tags: windows-defender, windows-11, microsoft-defender

How to disable Windows Defender in Windows 11 (Professional) (i.e. prevent `Antimaleware Service Executable` to spin up my (completely disconnected) Laptop's fans)?

The top answer of [Disable Windows Defender in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/947873/disable-windows-defender-in-windows-10) recommends to set `Turn off Windows Defender = Enabled` in `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Defender` with `gpedit.msc`. But said Configuration does not seem to exist in windows 11 (there is only "Windows Defender Smart Screen").

Comment: Only way is to permanently disable it, see my answer here, it can be restored easily if necessary>>>>https://superuser.com/a/1590129/40928

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Defender Antivirus is disabled, but back to normal after reboot. How to disable it permanently?](https://superuser.com/questions/1589730/microsoft-defender-antivirus-is-disabled-but-back-to-normal-after-reboot-how-t)

Comment: That is a Windows 10 answer from a while back. I do not think you can disable Windows 11 Defender permanently. Show me how if you can.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Disable Windows Defender scheduler tasks:**

   ```powershell
   Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object { $_.TaskName -like "Windows Defender*" } | Disable-ScheduledTask
   ```
2. **Boot to Safe Mode, then:**

   ```powershell
   msconfig

   # Disable related Windows Defender services:
     foreach ($SVC in "Sense", "WdBoot", "WdFilter", "WdNisDrv", "WdNisSvc", "WinDefend") {
       Set-ItemProperty -Path ("HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\" + $SVC) -Name Start -Value 4
     }
   ```
3. **Reboot → Windows Defender service should be deactivated:**

   ```powershell
   msconfig
   ```

Comment: It would be beneficial to list the steps required to enter Safe Mode as 2.1, moving #2's code box to 2.2

Comment: Out of the plenty ways I tried to disable Defender, this seems to be the only one working, thanks!