# No Windows Defender in Windows 11 Home

Tags: windows-11, windows-defender

I need to disable real time protection. For this reason I go to `Windows Security >> Virus & thread protection`. I got message `You'll need a new app to open this windowsdefender link` and link to `MS Store`. If I go this way I get message `No result found`
How to disable real time protection in Windows 11 Home?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you install Windows 11?

Comment: How Windows 11 was installed does not matter.  I answered this question last year.

Comment: You cannot, but you can remove Windefend completely>>>>https://superuser.com/a/1590129/40928