# Temporally deactivate antivirus

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus

On my new Windows 10 PC Sophos antivirus is preinstaled defenetly not the best antivirus programm, but since I have no other have to live with it. The bigest problem with it is the deletion of files which it thinks to be malicious without even asking me. Is there a way to temporally deactivate antivirus? I tried to shut it down with task manager, but that´s not working.
I have also instaled Malwarebytes which could replace Sophos, but it was not working. Looks like Malwarebytes is not compatible with Windows 10, since had exactly the same problem on some other Windows 10 PC.

Comment: It has become near impossible to turn off any AV installed in W10 or 11. I suggest to remove sophos and go back to defender. then read this on how to remove Defender>>>https://superuser.com/a/1590129/40928

Comment: Why do you think that you don't have Windows Defender? It's possible to disable it but not really to uninstall it. Defender is just as good as Sophos (if not more).

Comment: @harrymc Have no idea about Windows Defender, but it doesn´t seems to be a real antivirus. On my Windows 7 PC there is also Windows Defender, but it´s complete useles.

Comment: Defender has gone a lonnnggg way since the days of Windows 7. From being the worse antivirus it now gets as good notes as any other antivirus. And it has of course the best integration with Windows.

Comment: Your tag was Windows 10 , not 7 and WD is vastly better in Windows 10 and 11 than Windows 7

Comment: Many PC's are shipped with trial-ware, in the hopes that these games, office suites, anti-malware, etc. will be pucha$ed later. There are reputable free replacements for most.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik My antivirus is not trial-ware, this is the reason I am not willing to uninstal it.

Comment: I amended my answer that you should be sure to whitelist Apps / Files in Sophos causing issues. Temporarily disabling any AV (stopping the real time scanner) is not very practical these days.

Answer (score 1):

With Windows 10 (and 11) you definitely have options.

Windows Defender Anti Virus is built right into Windows 10 and is very good by itself.  I rely on Windows Defender myself.

If you need to, you can whitelist Apps and Files if WD thinks they are harmful (common to all AV).

Uninstall Sophos and then Windows Defender will take over.

You should be able to uninstall Sophos in Programs and Features.  Look also on the Sophos site for a complete uninstall App.

It is very difficult to temporarily stop any real time AV, so the best thing you can do is whitelist apps and files causing issues.

AV Apps including WD are hooked right into Windows core programs.

If you feel you wish to retain Sophos, make sure you whitelist any Apps or Files that are causing issues in Sophos.

Comment: I would like avoid uninstaling, the only real problem I have with Sophos is when it deletes files without my permision.

Comment: Look up Whitelisting in the Sophos documentation.  I also think having only one AV is better long term.